# from PIL import Image failed on Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm new to [Python](https://www.python.org/) and I have a problem with [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (as many people before me).

Running the command below:

`from PIL import Image`

causes a known error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

The problem occurs when I try to run it with Python 3.6, everything works fine with Python 3 however I have to use version 3.6 in my project.

Pillow version: 4.3.0, so it is compatible with this Python version.

Why does this not work on the newer version?

Comment: *"Everything works fine with python3"* - Which version exactly? Is it different from Python 3.6? Did you try to install it for Python 3.6? What happened? What OS are you using?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling Pillow and reinstalling with PIP. pip will make sure you get the compatible version of pillow for whatever python version you are using

Comment: @vaultah, I mean when I run `python3 reader.py` everything works, and `python3.6 reader.py` causes  this error. I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.
@AbdulrahmanAttia, yep, I've tried to uninstall it couple times. Doesn't work.

Comment: Then `python3` points to the Python 3.5.1 interpreter (on your machine). You'll have to install PIL separately for Python 3.6

Comment: @vaultah What do you mean? I've installed pillow with  `pip3 install pillow` comand

Comment: It's possible that if you have 2 python versions installed then the module might be installed to the wrong directory. Make sure you use pip3.6.exe not pip.exe or pip3.exe. Also, I'm not sure where this will be on Ubuntu, but you can check wiether it was installed or not in your python36-32 directory. You will find a file there called scripts. If you open it, you should see files like pilconverter.py, pildriver.py. If you cant see them, it means that pip was somehow not installed properley, or something wrong happened somewhere.

Comment: that means you might try 'pip3.6 install pillow' instead

Comment: the pip in python 3.6 is called 'pip3.6' not 'pip3'

Comment: I see, and I tried to use pip3.6 before, wasn't work. But maybe problem is here, I have to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install pillow for 3.6 python: `python3.6 -m pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

PIL and Python compatibility issue. See for example (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/installation.html ).

pipX search Pillow  -> shows which version is installed and available.

Better to use Python virtual environment to avoid compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip uninstall PIL
pip install Pillow
```

[Source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3825#issuecomment-346254569)

Answer (score -1):

C:\python>pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/d9/468422371e6fcf02d6a162ee30db4552221de8b2b3ff837363bf54cbb347/Pillow-6.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 3.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-6.1.0
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.